# Jordan-Hölder composition series of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ of integers modulo a

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $a$ be a strictly positive integer.

There exists one-to-one correspondence between the composition series of $(H_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ and the sequences $(s_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ of strictly positive integers such that 
$a=s_1...s_n$ and

$$[H_{i-1}:H_{i}]=s_i,\text{ for } 1\leq i\leq n .$$

Furthermore, $(H_i)$ is Jordan-Hölder if and only if $(s_i)$ is a sequence of primes.

Let $\mathfrak{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers.

Suppose $a=\prod_{p\in\mathfrak{P}} p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$, where $(\nu_{p}(a))_{p\in\mathfrak{P}}$ is a sequence of strictly positive integers with finite support.

Given *this* notation, i.e. $a=\prod_{p\in\mathfrak{P}} p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$, how can I apply the above to obtain a Jordan-Hölder composition series of $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$? The problem is that the result above refers to plain sequences $(s_i)$ without multiplicity, and yet here I have a factorization with multiplicity---how can I turn the sequence $(p^{\nu_{p}(a)})_{p\in\mathfrak{P}}$ into one that iterates all the factors one by one, according to their multiplicities?

For example, given $36=2^{2}3^{2}$, I want to turn the sequence $(2^{2},3^{2})$ into $(2,2,3,3)$.

I only want to be able to associate a Jordan-Hölder series to a factorization of the form $\prod_{p\in\mathfrak{P}} p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$; therefore I'll be happy with any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

$C_a = \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group of order $a$, so every subgroup is cyclic of order that divides $a$. Suppose that $a=p_1\dots p_n$ (not necessarily distinct). Then you just pick the sequence of cyclic groups

$$ 1 \lhd C_{p_1} \lhd C_{p_1p_2} \lhd \dots \lhd C_{p_1p_2\dots p_{n-1}} \lhd C_a$$

In your example, this would correspond to the sequence $(2,2,3,3)$

$$ 1 \lhd C_2 \lhd C_{4} \lhd C_{12} \lhd C_{36}$$

which, if $C_a = \langle x \rangle$, corresponds to the groups generated by 
$$ \langle x^{36} \rangle \lhd \langle x^{18}\rangle \lhd \langle x^{9}\rangle \lhd \langle x^{3}\rangle \lhd \langle x^1\rangle $$

Comment: I know that; I want to know how to do this for a factorization that includes multiplicity. The point precisely is to turn a sequence of distinct factors with multiplicity into a sequence of not necessarily distinct factors without multiplicity.

Comment: How do you propose to turn $(p^{\nu_{p}(a)})_{p\in\mathfrak{P}}$ into the sort of sequence you use in your answer?

Comment: If I get what you are asking, by writing each $p \in \mathcal{B}$ as $(p, p, \dots, p)$ ($\nu_p(a)$ times)

Comment: Yes, but I would like a formal solution to this.---For example, if I gave you the factorization $\prod p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$, what would be the associated Jordan Hölder series?

Comment: I gave you a pretty explicit procedure to construct it! If you want it to be more complicated: let $\mathcal{C}=\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ where $x_n=p$ has exactly $v_p(a)$ solutions for each $p$, and build the series $1\lhd N_1 \lhd \dots \lhd N_t = C_a$ as $N_j = C_{x_1\dots x_{j}}$.

Comment: Note that the solution is far from unique, any permutation of the primes will give you a different answer

Comment: But my point is that I don't have $a=p_1...p_n$---I have $a=\prod p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$. You seem to assert that that doesn't make a difference; I am not sure I understand why. The former expression is easy to iterate: the construction of the series merely involves adding an extra $p_i$ each time. But you can't do the same with the latter expression since each factor $p^{\nu_{p}(a)}$ is not a prime number but a power of a prime number.

Comment: There is a unique prime factorization of $p^{\nu_p(a)}$ as a product of $p$ $\nu_p(a)$ times. This one is even immune to permutations!